Swift JSON Decoding error wth coding Key usage
I would really appreciate some help. I have the following JSON returning from a laravel API backend
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "instructor",
        "hourly_rate": 35.01,
        "bio": "Patient and experienced driving instructor specialising in new drivers",
        "profile_image": null,
        "rating": 4.8,
        "total_reviews": 25,
        "location": {
            "latitude": 51.5074,
            "longitude": -0.1278
        },
        "qualifications": [
            "ADI Certificate",
            "Grade A Instructor"
        ],
        "years_experience": 5,
        "gender": "female",
        "transmission": "Manual",
        "vehicle_type": null,
        "lesson_types": [
            "standard",
            "intensive",
            "pass_plus"
        ],
        "is_available": true
    }
]

and the following model
struct Instructor: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let rating: Double
    let hourlyRate: Double
    let experience: Int
    let profileImage: String?
    let description: String
    let availability: [Availability]
    let gender: InstructorGender
    let lessonTypes: [LessonType]
    let transmission: TransmissionType
    let vehicleType: String?
    let qualifications: [String]
    let isAvailable: Bool
    
    struct Availability: Codable {
        let dayOfWeek: Int
        let startTime: Date
        let endTime: Date
    }
    
    enum TransmissionType: String, Codable {
        case manual = "Manual"
        case automatic = "Automatic"
    }
    
    enum LessonType: String, Codable {
        case standard = "standard"
        case intensive = "intensive"
        case passPlus = "pass_plus"
    }
    
    enum InstructorGender: String, Codable {
        case male
        case female
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let rawValue = try container.decode(String.self).lowercased()
            switch rawValue {
            case "male": self = .male
            case "female": self = .female
            default:
                throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid gender value: \(rawValue)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case rating
        case hourlyRate = "hourly_rate"
        case experience = "years_experience"
        case profileImage = "profile_image"
        case description = "bio"
        case availability
        case gender
        case lessonTypes = "lesson_types"
        case transmission
        case vehicleType = "vehicle_type"
        case qualifications
        case isAvailable = "is_available"
    }
}

When i use the the below decoder I get the error
ecoding error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "hourly_rate", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "hourly_rate", intValue: nil) ("hourly_rate").", underlyingError: nil))
private let jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder = {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        return decoder
    }()
    

func getBookings(token: String) async throws -> [Booking] {
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(baseURL)/bookings") else {
            throw NetworkError.invalidURL
        }

        let data = try await sendAuthenticatedRequestWithData(to: url, method: .get, token: token)

        if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(" Raw Bookings JSON:", jsonString)
        }

        do {
            let bookings = try jsonDecoder.decode([Booking].self, from: data)
            print(" Successfully decoded \(bookings.count) bookings")
            return bookings
        } catch {
            print("❌ Decoding error: \(error)")
            throw error
        }
    }


Add a question mark to hourly rate

why when it's not optional?

The key is missing according the error so it is either optional or you aren’t decoding what you think you are decoding

First issue: You are using decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase but as the same time using hard coded snake_case too. If you write case hourlyRate// = "hourly_rate" instead, it works... Then it's another issue, etc. Fix your issue piece by piece...

thnks this worked

you are decoding [Booking].self but you are showing us Instructor as if this is what you expect.
What is it that you get from the server?

You have declared hourlyRate as Double. But according to your JSON it is String.
So change let hourlyRate: Double to let hourlyRate: String.
Update
The error occurs because .convertFromSnakeCase automatically maps hourly_rate to hourlyRate, but your CodingKeys already maps it. This creates a conflict.
So remove decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase.

sorry, i had an old version of the json data, have updated with what i'm currently getting. it is not being returned as a string

Remove decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase and check.

thanks, this worked. I didn't realise i couldnt do both
